# StackOverflowException with Spring + Hibernate (ManyToMany relation)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

###### When using Hibernate in a Spring-boot application with ManyToMany entities, a StackOverflowException is thrown.

---

###### Tag.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "tag_name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<GiftCertificate> certificates;

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

###### GiftCertificate.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GiftCertificate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_duration")
    private int duration;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_create_date")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_id_last_update_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "gift_certificate_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gift_certificate_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

---

When receiving Tag or GiftCertificate data from the database and sending a response in the form of JSON, we will receive an error

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.prependPath(JsonMappingException.java:455) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:792) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
```

I used @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, but then the response has no commented @JsonBackReference field. I need both recieve both field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Using the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.

###### Tag.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "tag_name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("tags")
    private List<GiftCertificate> certificates;
}
```

###### GiftCertificate.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GiftCertificate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_duration")
    private int duration;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_create_date")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    @Column(name = "gift_certificate_id_last_update_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "gift_certificate_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gift_certificate_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("certificates")
    private List<Tag> tags;
```